# Move list from root site to subsite

Tags: 2010, list, import, export

We accidentally created a few lists at the root of our SharePoint 2010 site and need to move them to a subsite. How do you do this? We tried exporting as a template, but then the list became a library item. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there, the next step is to

- create a new list
- choose the template you saved
- after list created delete the template from the library.

[Full tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20121216190139/http://grounding.co.za/blogs/neil/archive/2008/10/05/moving-a-list-with-content-between-sharepoint-servers.aspx) (this is talking about between SharePoint servers, but its the same process between siets) [Broken link replaced with archive]

Other ways include

- If it a simple list you can perhaps use the DataSheet view to copy and paste the data to the new list if you've already setup the structure.
- You can copy lists with SharePoint Designer IIRC.
- You can also look at the [STSADM gl-exportlist and gm-importlist extensions](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/09/importexportcopy-lists/).

Comment: there are dedicated tools on the server side to do this. leaving the serverside will result in losing information like created, modified and also permissions are not transfered. If all of this is not needed your approach is a quick an easy solution.

Comment: You mean like STSADM gl-exportlist and gl-importlist? (I didn't notice the 2010 tag at first)

Comment: How do you move lists with SPD 2013?  I can't see a way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of exporting as a template, rather use the Sharepoint Backup Tools.

Browse to http://YOURCENTRALADMINURL:portnr/backups.aspx

Click "Export a site or list"

Select the List you want to backup.

Import into correct location using : `Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp`

Comment: Thanks, Fox. That's a very neat tool. I didn't know such a thing was possible. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This method is a bit risky. I've noticed loss of metadata such as Created by/Date etc.

Answer (score 3):

Please check these technet documents

Export list:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx

Import list:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428322.aspx

Sample Export:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://site -Path c:\export.cmp -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All -ItemUrl /lists/mylistname
```

Sample Import (path to subsite, list path will come out of the export):

```
Import-SPWeb http://site/subsite –Path c:\export.cmp –UpdateVersions -Overwrite -IncludeUserSecurity
```

Comment: Thanks, Marco. Those are some nifty export/import links and commands.